# How to display two data textfiled in kendo treeview in client side

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to display name and id filed in kendo treeview. the below one is not working

```
$("#trainingtreelist").kendoTreeView({
                dataTextField:"name"+"id",
                dataSource: data
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared a simple dojo for you showing you how to template the items being displayed in the treeview.

https://dojo.telerik.com/IsUZewoX

the important thing to look at here is the config of the treeview:

```
  $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
     template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
     dataSource: ...remove for brevity
});
```

then using the template outlined here:

```
 <script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
            #: item.text # <span style="border:1px solid black; margin:3px;padding:10px; font-weight:bold; "> #:item.id#</span>

            # if (!item.items) { #
                <a class='k-icon k-i-close-outline' href='\#'></a>
            # } #
        </script>
```

we can `restyle` the items how we like. I have simply taken the demo templating example from: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/templates and added the id and styled that so it is noticeable (contained in the bordered box).